# Can any one help me to find the Microsoft.VisualStudio.SourceSafe.Interop .dll?

Tags: c#-4.0

Could anyone help me where to find the Microsoft.VisualStudio.SourceSafe.Interop .dll?I did not find the dll in my system.Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

The interop dll is a wrapper around a COM object. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssourcecontrol/thread/284367ac-f8a7-411f-bca5-293bd827e3e9) for further reference.

Comment: Could you please explain me in detail?